# Making message content a variable discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def makereactionrole(ctx):
    await ctx.send('What would you like the title to be?')
    title = ''
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and mesg.channel == ctx.channel
        title = msg.content
    await ctx.send(title)
```

**Error**: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Trying to make the response of 'What would you like the title to be?' a varible which will send back as a test. Please help.

Comment: Can you format code with right indent?

Comment: Yup your indentation is incorrect

Comment: @mundanehassan What is supposed to be changed? I have never ran into a error with my indenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `wait_for` here is an example.

```py
import asyncio

@bot.command()
async def makereactionrole(ctx):
    def author_and_channel(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
    
    await ctx.send("Please enter a title")

    #timeout is in sec
    try:
        title_msg = await bot.wait_for('message',
                                       check=author_and_channel,
                                       timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.channel.send(f'Sorry, you took too long to respond')

    title = title_msg.content
    print(title)
```

Docs:
[`Bot.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: The goal with the function is to make it ask all of the questions and get individual responses then bring it all together in a reaction role. All i need to do is figure out how to get the first question to work before I add more.

Comment: You looking for `wait_for` I will add it

Comment: Have you added it anywhere?

Comment: Now you can see it above :)

Answer (score 1):

In the last line of your shared code

```
await ctx.send(title)
```

it sends the `title` variable as message but since `title` variable on your third line of your shared code is empty.

```
title = ''
```

that is why the problem occured